# Initializing an arry for Nim game in the constructor

Tags: java

I have no idea how to make this constructor for my homework. Can someone lead me in the right direction? I'm new to Java and I'm having a hard time with this. I copied this part out of my homework. After I get this part done Ill be able to do the rest. Thanks!

```
public NimGame(int[] initialSticks) { }
```

This constructor should create a new game with the initial number of sticks in each row set to the 
corresponding elements of initialSticks.

For example, to create a game with initially 3, 5, and 7 sticks, this would be called as

```
new NimGame(new int[]{3, 5, 7});
```

Comment: You can alternatively pass any number of `int`s using, `public NimGame(int... initialSticks) { }`, This way you don't have to use `new int...`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the numbers as an array in your object, you could do it like this:

```
class NimGame {
    private int[] sticks;
    public NimGame(int[] initialSticks) {
        this.sticks = initialSticks.clone();
    }
}
```

Then you can construct a new `NimGame` object as `new NimGame(new int[] { 3, 5, 7})` as you specified.